# azure pipeline how to trigger build from jenkins server and copy files from with self-hosted linux agent to hosted agent and build on hosted agent

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

my scenario is like this

1. I have Jenkins server which triggers build flow ( this can't be changed )
2. the source code is checkout out from 3 repos to the Jenkins  server
3. the files get manipulated and changed on the Jenkins server
4. I installed azure self-hosted Linux agent in the Jenkins server.
   And it is online as I see it on the azure DevOps dashboard.
   in the Azure DevOps, i defined a project that checkouts simple azure-pipelines.yml.
   I want to copy files from the Jenkins server to the azure hosted agent and build there the files.
   then after the build is done I want to copy back the files to the Jenkins server

my missing part is how do i start the steps in the pipeline in the hosted azure that will listen to the self-hosted Linux server agent that it needs to copy the files?
also how i do trigger the self-hosted server to trigger pipeline steps in the hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal... But what you could do:

- disable all triggers on your azure pipeline
- disable the repo checkout steps
- add a `queue time` variable that can hold the location of the contents.
- add a `queue time` variable that can hold the target location of the outcome.
- on jenkins copy the contents to a central location
- on jenkins, use the Rest API to trigger your Azure Pipelines build, pass the queue time variable
- on Azure Pipelines add a script at the start to grab the contents from the variable location
- on Azure Pipelines add a script at the end to copy the contents from the variable location
- on Jenkins, use the REST API in a loop to detect the status of the pipeline

To get started:

- [The docs to the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Comment: this is most be the worng way to do stuff .... no way I'm going to implement it in production

Comment: To me it just doesnt really make sense to split the job between Jenkins and Pipelines... There is a way to start the pipeline from Pipelines and have it trigger Jenkins...

Comment: the only sense is that i need to use the azure mac agent , this is way i need azure